How to fix modified cargo dependencies
Suppose I accidentally delete or modify the source files of a crate in my ~/.cargo/registry/ directory and it causes my compilation to fail. Is there a way I can get cargo to check all my downloaded dependencies and fix / redownload the ones that were modified?

you should delete the entire ~/.cargo/registry directory  because this will force cargo to re-download all the dependencies the next time you build your project. you can use this command:
rm -rf ~/.cargo/registry

in addition, you can use cargo clean to remove the target directory, which contains the build artifacts. Then you rebuild the project using cargo build  command
